# Error in Delete a file in a while loop with being used by another process error

Tags: c#, .net

This is a piece of my code and I want to delete a file (line 12).

But an error raises: the project cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in c# exactly in second time of the while loop. I disposed and closed every
object.

```
while (true)
{
    string strEncrypted;
    int strLenght = 0;
    byte[] cryptedRGB;

    string imgCamFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\___imgCam\\_sentImg\\__empImg.bmp";
    if (File.Exists(@imgCamFile))
    {
        lock (@imgCamFile)
        {
            //if (camPictureBox.Image != null)
            //    camPictureBox.Image.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
            System.IO.File.Delete(@imgCamFile);
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    strDataType = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Frame");
    strEncrypted = clsCryption.Encrypt("Frame");

    strDataType = new byte[strEncrypted.Length];
    foreach (char c in strEncrypted.ToCharArray())
    {
        strDataType[strLenght] = (byte)c;
        strLenght++;
    }
    if (optClient.Checked == true)
        mClient.Send(strDataType);
    else if (optServer.Checked == true)
        mServerHandler.Send(strDataType);

    MemoryStream Ms = new MemoryStream();
    camPictureBox.Image.Save(Ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] mData = Ms.GetBuffer();
    Ms.Close();
    Ms.Dispose();

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgCamFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    fileStream.Write(mData, 0, mData.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    fileStream.Dispose();

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imgCamFile);
    Size mS = bitmap.Size;

    string[,] RGB = new string[mS.Width * 3, mS.Height];
    int realWodth = mS.Width * 3;
    byte[] myRGB = new byte[realWodth * mS.Height];

    int cCounter = 0;
    int pRow = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < mS.Height; y++)
    {
        cCounter = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < mS.Width; x++)
        {
            Color pixColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

            RGB[cCounter, y] = pixColor.R.ToString(); ++cCounter;
            RGB[cCounter, y] = pixColor.G.ToString(); ++cCounter;
            RGB[cCounter, y] = pixColor.B.ToString(); ++cCounter;

            myRGB[pRow] = Byte.Parse(pixColor.R.ToString()); pRow++;
            myRGB[pRow] = Byte.Parse(pixColor.G.ToString()); pRow++;
            myRGB[pRow] = Byte.Parse(pixColor.B.ToString()); pRow++;
        }

    }

    int sent;
    if (optClient.Checked == true)
        sent = SendVarData(mClient, myRGB);
    else if (optServer.Checked == true)
        sent = SendVarData(mServerHandler, myRGB);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
}
```

Comment: It is a really bad sign that you need to do a GC.Collect() -- a well designed program should not need to take such action -- why do you feel you need to do so? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Comment: This code needs breaking up into methods at the very least.

Comment: [MSDN using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why all the steps?  `Image -> MemoryStream -> FileStream -> BitMap`

`Bitmap` is an `Image` -- are you sure that `camPictureBox.Image` isn't already a `Bitmap` and you can't do your calculations with it instead?

If not...

```
using(var bitmap = new Bitmap(camPictureBox.Image))
{
   // do your calculations
}
```

... or ...

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   camPictureBox.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

   using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(ms))
   {
       // do your work
   }
}
```

Comment: I've used Memory stream to read all byte of my frame and change it to byte.And use file stream to save it . and use Bitmap to fetch its size and work on its pixels. Did i do any mistake or do you have any batter solution for me ?

Comment: I posed three different solutions.  You shouldn't need to save it to disk to use it in code -- the FileStream step is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem :

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imgCamFile);
```

You never set bitmap to null so that is keeping a lock on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, I agree. You should not call Garbage Collector. C# should do it automatically. Just dispose all the objects to release resources.

Remember that this is not needed:

```
Ms.Close();
Ms.Dispose();

fileStream.Close();
fileStream.Dispose();
```

Because dispose implicitly calls close.

Release the resources after using Bitmap class:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imgCamFile); 
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: [MSDN using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx)